# Single-thread Task Scheduler with type erasure and allocator-aware

Tags: c++, memory-management, timer, c++17, type-safety

I made a task scheduler to practice allocators and type erasure. With my project, you can delay execution of any callable (functions (using `std::ref`), lambdas...) in time by inserting it in a `TaskScheduler`, and by giving a `std::chrono::time_point` (you can also make a task be called multiple times by giving a period (`std::chrono::duration`) and optionally a number of call)).

This project does not use threads, so to make the tasks called, you have to call `TaskScheduler::update` (likely in a main loop), which will then call the tasks if needed. I have only basic knowledge on multi-threading so if you have any advice in order to make `TaskScheduler` thread-safe, I am interested.

Moreover, I have implemented type-erasure (so any callable can fit in the `TaskScheduler`) so I am interested on comments about the type-safety of this implementation.

Here is the code :

**TaskScheduler.h**

```cpp
#ifndef TASK_SCHEDULER_J_VERNAY
#define TASK_SCHEDULER_J_VERNAY
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <tuple>

class TaskTraits {
public:
    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using time_point = clock::time_point;
    using duration = clock::duration;
};

class Task {
    friend class TaskScheduler;
public:
    TaskTraits::time_point when() const noexcept { return _when; }
    void delay(TaskTraits::duration delay_) noexcept { _when += delay_; }
    void set_when(TaskTraits::time_point when_) noexcept { _when = when_; }
    void cancel() noexcept { _fun = nullptr; }
    void execute() { if (_fun) (*_fun)(*this); }

    // for usage in std::sort for TaskScheduler
    static bool before(Task const& a, Task const& b) noexcept { return a._when < b._when; }
private:
    Task(void(*fun_)(Task&), void* args_, std::size_t size_, TaskTraits::time_point when_) noexcept :
        _fun{fun_}, _args{args_}, _size{size_}, _when{when_}
    {}
    TaskTraits::time_point _when;
    void(*_fun)(Task&);
    void* _args;
    std::size_t _size;
};

class TaskScheduler : private std::pmr::vector<Task> {
    using _base = vector;
public:

    using _base::value_type;
    using _base::reference;
    using _base::const_reference;
    using _base::difference_type;
    using _base::size_type;
    using _base::allocator_type;
    using _base::iterator;
    using _base::const_iterator;
    using _base::reverse_iterator;
    using _base::const_reverse_iterator;

    TaskScheduler(allocator_type a_ = {}) : _base(a_) {}
    TaskScheduler(TaskScheduler const& ts_, allocator_type a_ = {}) : _base(ts_, a_) {}
    TaskScheduler(TaskScheduler&& ts_) noexcept : _base(ts_) {}
    TaskScheduler(TaskScheduler&& ts_, allocator_type a_ = {}) noexcept : _base(ts_, a_) {}

    template<typename Fun>
    void insert(TaskTraits::time_point when_, Fun const& fun_);
    template<typename Fun>
    void insert_loop(TaskTraits::time_point when_, TaskTraits::duration loop_, Fun const& fun_);
    template<typename Fun>
    void insert_loop(TaskTraits::time_point when_, TaskTraits::duration loop_, int nbloops_, Fun const& fun_);

    void update();

    // with these iterators, you could first: sort the tasks with std::sort and Task::before,
    // then: iterate by chronological order. But notice the order will likely be modified by update()!
    using _base::begin;
    using _base::end;
    using _base::cbegin;
    using _base::cend;
    using _base::rbegin;
    using _base::rend;
    using _base::crbegin;
    using _base::crend;

    using _base::empty;
    using _base::size;
    using _base::clear;
    void erase(iterator pos) noexcept; // O(1) because order is not preserved

private:
    std::pmr::memory_resource* get_resource() const { return get_allocator().resource(); }
    template<typename Fun>
    void* store_args(Fun const&);
};

template<typename Fun>
void* TaskScheduler::store_args(Fun const& fun_) {
    void* args = nullptr;
    if constexpr (sizeof(fun_) <= sizeof(void*)) {
        get_allocator().construct(reinterpret_cast<Fun*>(&args), fun_);
    } else {
        args = get_resource()->allocate(sizeof(fun_));
        get_allocator().construct(reinterpret_cast<Fun*>(args), fun_);
    }
    return args;
}

template<typename Fun>
void TaskScheduler::insert(TaskTraits::time_point when_, Fun const& fun_) {
    void* args = store_args(fun_);

    auto fun = static_cast<void(*)(Task&)>(
        [](Task& t) {
            if constexpr (sizeof(Fun) <= sizeof(void*))
                reinterpret_cast<Fun&>(t._args)();
            else
                (*reinterpret_cast<Fun*>(t._args))();
            t.cancel();
        });


    push_back(Task(fun, args, sizeof(fun_), when_));
}


template<typename Fun>
void TaskScheduler::insert_loop(TaskTraits::time_point when_, TaskTraits::duration loop_, Fun const& fun_) {
    auto data = std::make_tuple(fun_, loop_);
    using data_t = decltype(data);
    void* args = store_args(data);

    auto fun = static_cast<void(*)(Task&)>(
        [](Task& t) {
            data_t* data = nullptr;
            if constexpr (sizeof(data_t) <= sizeof(void*))
                data = reinterpret_cast<data_t*>(&t._args); 
            else
                data = reinterpret_cast<data_t*>(t._args);
            std::get<Fun>(*data)();
            t.delay(std::get<TaskTraits::duration>(*data));
        });
    push_back(Task(fun, args, sizeof(data_t), when_));
}
template<typename Fun>
void TaskScheduler::insert_loop(TaskTraits::time_point when_, TaskTraits::duration loop_, int nbloops_, Fun const& fun_) {
    if (nbloops_ <= 0) return;
    auto data = std::make_tuple(fun_, loop_, nbloops_);
    using data_t = decltype(data);
    void* args = store_args(data);

    auto fun = static_cast<void(*)(Task&)>(
        [](Task& t) {
            data_t* data = nullptr;
            if constexpr (sizeof(Fun) <= sizeof(void*))
                data = reinterpret_cast<data_t*>(&t._args); 
            else
                data = reinterpret_cast<data_t*>(t._args);
            std::get<Fun>(*data)();
            if (--std::get<int>(*data) <= 0)
                t.cancel();
            else
                t.delay(std::get<TaskTraits::duration>(*data));
        });
    push_back(Task(fun, args, sizeof(data_t), when_));
}

#endif //TASK_SCHEDULER_J_VERNAY
```

**TaskScheduler.cpp**

```cpp
#include "TaskScheduler.h"

void TaskScheduler::update() {
    TaskTraits::time_point now = TaskTraits::clock::now();
    std::size_t userdata_size = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0, c = size(); i < c; ++i) {
        auto task = begin() + i;
        while (task->when() < now) {
            task->execute();
            if (!task->_fun) {
                erase(task);
                --c;
                if (i >= c) return;
                task = begin() + i;
            }
        }
    }
}

void TaskScheduler::erase(TaskScheduler::iterator pos) noexcept {
    if (pos->_size > sizeof(void*))
        get_resource()->deallocate(pos->_args, pos->_size);
    *pos = back();
    pop_back();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <thread> // std::this_thread::sleep_for
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "TaskScheduler.h"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
void print_the_end() { std::printf("==== THE END ====\n"); }


int main() {
    std::string a = "Hello", b = "World";

    auto begin = TaskTraits::clock::now();
    TaskScheduler ts;
    ts.insert_loop(begin, 200ms, 25, [begin, &a, i = 0]() mutable { // looping during 200ms * 25 = 5s
        auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(TaskTraits::clock::now() - begin);
        std::printf("Iter %2d, t=%4dms : a = %s\n", ++i, (int)ms.count(), a.c_str());
    });

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) // changing a every 1 second
        ts.insert(begin + 500ms + i * 1s, [&a, b, i] {
            a[i] = b[i];
            std::printf("== a has changed! ==\n");
        });

    ts.insert(begin + 5s, std::ref(print_the_end));

    while (!ts.empty()) { // main loop
        ts.update();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5ms);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Possible output**

```
Iter  1, t=   0ms : a = Hello
Iter  2, t= 200ms : a = Hello
Iter  3, t= 402ms : a = Hello
== a has changed! ==
Iter  4, t= 605ms : a = Wello
Iter  5, t= 802ms : a = Wello
Iter  6, t=1004ms : a = Wello
Iter  7, t=1200ms : a = Wello
Iter  8, t=1402ms : a = Wello
== a has changed! ==
Iter  9, t=1605ms : a = Wollo
Iter 10, t=1801ms : a = Wollo
Iter 11, t=2001ms : a = Wollo
Iter 12, t=2202ms : a = Wollo
Iter 13, t=2404ms : a = Wollo
== a has changed! ==
Iter 14, t=2602ms : a = Worlo
Iter 15, t=2804ms : a = Worlo
Iter 16, t=3002ms : a = Worlo
Iter 17, t=3202ms : a = Worlo
Iter 18, t=3401ms : a = Worlo
== a has changed! ==
Iter 19, t=3601ms : a = Worlo
Iter 20, t=3801ms : a = Worlo
Iter 21, t=4002ms : a = Worlo
Iter 22, t=4201ms : a = Worlo
Iter 23, t=4402ms : a = Worlo
== a has changed! ==
Iter 24, t=4602ms : a = World
Iter 25, t=4801ms : a = World
==== THE END ====
```

Thank you for any review! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like:

- good include-guards, unlikely to collide with others
- careful use of scoped names
- efficient storage of small values (though the repeated access code could perhaps be refactored to a utility method in `Task`)

I dislike:

- identifiers that differ only in `_` prefix or suffix
- pointless parens around value arguments to `sizeof` that make them look like type arguments
- our types are in the global namespace

Specific issues:

- > ```
  > Task(void(*fun_)(Task&), void* args_, std::size_t size_, TaskTraits::time_point when_) noexcept :
  >     _fun{fun_}, _args{args_}, _size{size_}, _when{when_}
  > {}
  > ```

  It's misleading to write the `_when` initializer last, as it will be initialized first.  In this specific case, it doesn't matter, because there's no interdependencies, but I recommend always writing the initializers in the same order as the members.
- > ```
  > void TaskScheduler::update() {
  >     std::size_t userdata_size = 0;
  > ```

  This local variable is never used.
- I don't see any reason why `Task` needs to be a publicly-visible class.  Since we can't insert or obtain one, it should probably be a private `struct` within `TaskScheduler`.
- When scheduling new tasks, we ought to accept a forwarding reference to a `Fun`, and use `std::fwd()` as appropriate, rather than copying from a const reference.
- We're over-constraining the allocator by letting the alignment default to `alignof(std::max_align_t)` rather than using the actual alignment requirements like this:

  ```
  args = get_resource()->allocate(sizeof fun_, alignof(Fun));
  ```
- The linear search for tasks to run might be a performance drag when there are lots of tasks.  This is a problem for which the *heap* structure is a perfect fit (`std::priority_queue`).

Comment: Thank you for your review. `Task` is publicly-visible because you can iterate using begin(), end(), etc, so that you can cancel tasks or delay some. Because of this, something like a heap (or sorting using std::sort) should be recreated each `update` call

Comment: If you're adding tasks one at a time, then don't sort each time - just use `std::binary_search` to insert each item in the right place.  You'll still pay for moving the subsequent elements, but that's less than sorting the whole container.  Or change to a `std::multiset`.